# How to retry multiple times a Promise function?

Tags: javascript, promise

in my application, I have a promised function "serverGet()" which makes a server call. At times, the server returns me an HTTP 200 response but with an empty object. If I try 2 or 3 times, I get the full JSON.
Time to find a final solution, I want to create a JS script allowing to re-execute this promised function a number of times until I get the result.

Here is what I developed but unfortunately, it does not return anything on retry 4-3-2-1 :

```
function promiseWithRetry(fn, retries){

    console.log("retry :"+retries);

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        fn.then(function(response){

            if(_.isEmpty(response) && retries > 0){
                console.log("start new retry");
                Promise.resolve(promiseWithRetry(fn, retries-1));

            }else{
                console.log("resolve");
                resolve(response);
            }

        });
    });
}

promiseWithRetry(serverGet(parameters), 5).then(function(response){
  console.log(response)
});
```

To simulate serverGet(), I have written in jsfiddle a small random function so execute the code several times to test it :

https://jsfiddle.net/christophes/krgvsfcy/

Can you help me ?

Christophe

Comment: If `fn` was supposed to be a function (and it needs to be!), you need to call it like `fn()`, and also actually pass a function not a promise.

Comment: Also, avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)! (Btw, `Promise.resolve(…)` instead of `resolve(…)` never worked)

Comment: I would advise you to search for the "iterative promises" (or even "recursive") keywords

Comment: @Bergi I'm not sure to understand. Can you give me an example ? I can't do `fn().then(function(response){...`

Comment: I have updated the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/christophes/krgvsfcy/

Comment: @christophes Yes, you can and should do exactly that.

Comment: @Bergi If I do this, I have the error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: fn is not a function` . https://jsfiddle.net/christophes/krgvsfcy/7/

Comment: As I said, you need to "*actually pass a function not a promise*".

Comment: @Bergi Ok, but in my case I have not the choice. The serverGet function is a part of an API and is a promise. Do you have another idea?

Comment: No, it's a function that returns a promise. Don't call it, pass a function that calls it. `function doCall() { return serverGet(parameters); } promiseWithRetry(doCall, 5)` or alternatively `promiseWithRetry(() => serverGet(parameters), 5)`

Comment: @christophes I updated your jsfiddle with an example; https://jsfiddle.net/79g4nmxe/1/. I hope it's useful for you, I added some comments as well so you may understand better how `.then` and `.catch` works.

Comment: Thanks @JiFus ! I love this code. It's more clear to use try/catch. But there is still a bug. When we have an error, the retry are restarted but it do not call back the server. I added "BAD response" and "GOOD response" logs and as you can see in my test, I never have any answer if there is more than 1 retry  https://jsfiddle.net/christophes/7r3sk58b/13/

Comment: Hi @christophes. This is because we're still passing the promise of the response to the server by reference. If you want the randomness to be recalculated every time, you need to pass the generator function `serverGet` instead of the promise we get as a result from calling `serverGet`. Check the updated fiddle to see what I mean; https://jsfiddle.net/2casn6tr/

Comment: OK @JiFus , so if I understand, I've not the choice. If I want to pass parameters, I need to add another argument in my function : `promiseWithRetry(fn, arg, retries)` , like this : https://jsfiddle.net/christophes/7r3sk58b/20/

Comment: Or you could go with some syntactic sugar: https://jsfiddle.net/kj9o1vwL/. Pass the `PromiseWithRetry` function a generator instead that uses the function you wish to call with the arguments.